# Printing JSON data member into console with angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to access JSON object member using angularjs. I can print the whole json object array but can't access the member of the object uniquely.

```
          $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
          $scope.datainput =[];

          $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: 'Data/input.json'
        }).then(function (data){
           $scope.datainput=data;
           //console.log($scope.datainput);
           console.log($scope.datainput);


        },function (error){
           console.log("big error");
        });



        var json=JSON.parse($scope.datainput);
        console.log(json[0].status);
```

I have tried this code also but still geting the same error .

```
           $scope.temp = "";
           $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
           $scope.datainput =[];


        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Data/input.json'
         }).then(function (data){
            $scope.datainput=data;
            //console.log($scope.datainput);
            console.log($scope.datainput);

          var json=JSON.parse($scope.datainput);
          console.log(json[0].status);

         },function (error){
            console.log("big error");
         });
```

json file `input.json`:

```
[
    {"status":"payfail","value":"310"},
    {"status":"payinit","value":"100"},
    {"status":"paysuccess","value":"200"},
    {"status":"payreturn","value":"50"}

]
```

I get this error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()

The solution will be this....

```
           $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
           $scope.datainput =[];


        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Data/input.json'
         }).then(function (data){
            $scope.datainput=data.data;
            //console.log(data);



            console.log($scope.datainput);

            var json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.datainput));
            console.log(json[0].status);


         },function (error){
            console.log("big error");
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you are trying to parse the JSON string before it has been returned by the promise.

Try putting your parsing code inside the then block so that it executes in the correct order.

*Upon further investigation, here is an updated Answer:*

In addition to fixing the promise execution order, it turns out there is an issue with the way that you are accessing the data on the response variable.

Check the documentation for $http here: [W3Schools.com $http doco](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

You will see that the callback response value actually contains a member called data for the response payload.  To get this working try accessing the data member on the response object.

```
$scope.datainput=data.data;
```

It would probably be a good idea to also rename the data response object from data to response for readability.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the data object to the console to see if you are getting anything back from the HTTP request?

Comment: It worked as a whole object .But It doesn't work If I want to access member uniquely.

Comment: It sounds to me like the response may not be valid JSON?  If you are getting undefined from the Parse call that would typically mean that it is unable to parse the input string.

Comment: Than what can I do about it to access all the member uniquely?

Comment: Well the first step is to ensure that the response from your service is JSON.  I expect if you were to hardcode the JSON into the json object the parse option would work fine.

Comment: As a test, try replacing:

`$scope.datainput=data;`

with:

`$scope.datainput=[
    {"status":"payfail","value":"310"},
    {"status":"payinit","value":"100"},
    {"status":"paysuccess","value":"200"},
    {"status":"payreturn","value":"50"}
];`

Comment: This is giving correct output but I want to import this object from a json file.

Comment: Excellent, that is showing us that the code used to parse the JSON and access the correct member is working as expected.  The problem here is that the data being returned in the response is not valid JSON.

Can you dump the data variable to the console and post it here?

Comment: If I could give a screenshot it would be better.  

data: Array(4)
0: {status: "payfail", value: "310"}
1: {status: "payinit", value: "100"}
2: {status: "paysuccess", value: "200"}
3: {status: "payreturn", value: "50"}
length: 4

Comment: I have a feeling you are not accessing the data of the reponse correctly.  Have a look at this doco for $http.  

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

In this example I think you should actually be using the data.data variable.

`$scope.datainput=data.data`

Comment: Thank you Ben now its completely working.Thank you for your effort Ben.You can give a updated answer in the answer section such that other will get help.

Comment: You should add the full code after update @BenFarrelly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to solve that:

```
$scope.rows = []; // init empty array
  $scope.datainput =[];

          $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: 'Data/input.json'
        }).then(function (data){
           $scope.datainput=data.data;
           console.log($scope.datainput);

        var json= angular.fromJson($scope.datainput); 
         console.log(json[0].status);

        },function (error){
           console.log("big error");
        });
```

You should'n write `Json.Parse` out function `Get` you should write this code  inside the then block and use `data.data` to get the data from `json` file.

Comment: Still getting the same error.I have tried that before.Now I have tried that again.

Comment: "angular.min.js:127 TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"     

now I am getting this error

Comment: Thank for your effort @Feras but its still giving the same error.

Comment: can you give me feedback what `var json` retrieve data

Comment: Json var could not retrieve any data.It simply giving error. But  "console.log($scope.datainput);"  this command is printing the whole object.

Comment: Its still giving  "angular.min.js:127 TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined" this error

Comment: You should add `data.data` to get the data from `json` file,I update the answer